# What is a good strategy for data masking?

Tags: document-library, security, replication

Can anyone recommend a good strategy for data masking in SharePoint 2010?

How do you replicate live data in development and test environment whilst preserving data security and removing sensitive information from metadata and documents (Word, Excel, PDF, msg etc)?

The system in question is a document management solution but I'd be interested in knowing what solutions others are using / have come up with for other implementation types as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is generally no good solution for this. Might be so that there are some 3rd party vendors out there with their "so-called" SharePoint replication engines, cannot recommend any of them for this type of job.

Looks like you got to roll your own process/application/tool for this.

Comment: Thought so from having looked around a bit. Thanks for your answer.